# Qual combo foi selecionado dentro de um formulário

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Olá,
Dentro de um formulário tenho 4 combos

```
<select name="combo1" ><option value="combo1">Combo 1</option> </select>
<select name="combo2" ><option value="combo2">Combo 2</option> </select>
<select name="combo3" ><option value="combo3">Combo 3</option> </select>
<select name="combo4" ><option value="combo4">Combo 4</option> </select>
```

Quando algum combo for selecionado preciso saber dentre esses quatros, qual foi o selecionado (se foi o 1 ou 2 ou 3 ou 4) e pegar o valor do combo selecionado.

Obrigado.

Comment: Utilize o evento `onchange` em cada combo, assim quando houver alterações, você consegue pegar. Veja mais em [W3Schools - OnChangeEvent](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer asssim:

```js
$('select[name^=combo]').change(function() {
  console.log('select:', this.name)
  console.log('valor selecionado:', this.value)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="combo1" >
  <option value=""></option> 
  <option value="combo1">Combo 1</option> 
</select>

<select name="combo2" >
  <option value=""></option> 
  <option value="combo2">Combo 2</option> 
</select>

<select name="combo3" >
  <option value=""></option> 
  <option value="combo3">Combo 3</option> 
</select>

<select name="combo4" >
  <option value=""></option> 
  <option value="combo4">Combo 4</option> 
</select>
```